# Can you run serial, POE and HDbaseT through a patch panel?

Tags: cabling, layer1, patch-panel

**Short question**

Can we run Serial, HDbaseT and POE through a patch panel ? The patch panel will also be serving the data network.

**Long question (with more background info)**

Ive got a patch panel going into an office for a data network, in addition to the data network we also have some HDbaseT baluns (HD video over cat6), serial commands (for controlling AV kit via a control system) and some POE devices (such as access point and door entry panel.

All of the above devices run over cat6, and in the case of the serial get put into an rj45 to rs232 convertor.

I know that we cant run all of this through a network switch, but can we run this through a patch panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A patch panel is really just part of your cable plant, and it is merely the termination point.

If you were smart, you would have different patch panels for different functions, but you could do it all on one patch panel if you carefully mark what each connection is. You have three different, incompatible functions, and you really don't want to accidentally connect cabling for one function to a source for a different function.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Ron.  It's all copper connections.  Ensure you stay within recommendations for length.  HDbase-T is the same as Ethernet (328'), but serial is limited.

There is some good info here.
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/serial-distance.html

That said, with a 16 port DECServer I'm able to push 9600 to medical lab equipment that's over 100' away quite reliably.